# Is it good practice to cast an entity type inside EF Core Linq Statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I am using Entity Framework Core 3.1 in a Xamarin Forms 4.8 app with Sqlite.

For the entities, I have a little inheritance tree and use an Interface to mark a certain type of entities. Structure is stated below. In my data access I have some methods only allowed for entities implementing the Interface `INotificationEntity`. Data Access uses Generics with constraint of types beeing of type `Entity`, thus I check at runtime if the entity is implementing `INotificationEntity`. `Entity` itself is never implementing `INotificationEntity`.

In my data access I use following code, where I cast to the interface in a Where and a CountAsync() statement:

```
public abstract class DataAccess<TTaskData, TEntity> : DataAccessBase,
        IDataAccess<TData>
        where TData : Data
        where TEntity : Entity, new()
     ...

    public async Task<int> CountAsync() 
    {
    ...
    // usage in CountAsync
    return await dbSet.CountAsync(x => ((INotificationEntity)x).NotificationState != NotificationState.Done);
    ...
    }

    public async Task<int> GetPendingAsync(int tvdNumber) 
    {
    ....
    // usage in Where
    var result = await dbSet
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => ((INotificationEntity)x).NotificationState != NotificationState.Done)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDate)
                .ToListAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
     ...
     }
```

Simplified structure of entities:

```
public interface INotificationEntity
{
    NotificationState NotificationState { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationEntity : Entity, INotificationEntity
{
    public NotificationState NotificationState { get; set; }
}
```

Code is compiling and working. What I do not 100% know, if there are any unwanted things happening. As far as I understand docs, EF Core 3.1 would throw Exceptions if this would lead to a client evaluated query. But are there any other possible traps or implications?

Why I am doing this? I just like to avoid having larger inheritance trees for data access, entities, interfaces and everything.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to add `INotificationEntity` to the constraints in those methods? Save yourself the casting.

Comment: @insane_developer The generic declaration and its constraints are on class level, not on method level. Implementing classes then declare what actual class they use to override the data access base class.

Comment: Note that if the query is entirely executed on the server, the casting might be a no-op. I.e., it is required in your C# code to make it compile, but it will probably not generate any additional SQL code. (Profile your query to see what it does.)

Comment: Your `DataAccess` class allows more than `INotificationEntity`s so the cast may fail.

Comment: @GertArnold I am aware of this and check before if the type implements the interface.

Comment: @this.myself checking whether an object implements an interface kind of defeats the purpose of using generics, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that EF-Core translates the lambda expressions to SQL. SQL doesn't know anything about interfaces. It understands that an access to a column named `NotificationState` on a specific table is required. Your cast does not affect the value returned by this column (like converting a number to a string would).

So, either the column exists, in which case the query succeeds, or it will fail with an "Invalid column name" error. But this cast will not be translated to SQL. It is a no-op. The lambda expression (and thus the cast) will never be executed on the client side.

Use [Logging in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/logging-in-entityframework-core.aspx) to see the SQL generated or use a profiler (like SQL Server Profiler).

Update (OP):
Additonal to the given correct answer above I like to add the generated Sql statements as proof.

```cs
 // Linq sample with CountAsync()
 return await dbSet.CountAsync(x => ((INotificationTask)x).NotificationState !=
                                      NotificationState.Done);
```

```sql
// Generated Sql:
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM "BTable" AS "b"
  WHERE ("b"."NotificationState" <> 1)
```

```
// Linq Samle with Where / ToList
 var result = await dbSet
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => ((INotificationTask)x).NotificationState != NotificationState.Done &&
                ((INotificationTask)x).TvdNumber == tvdNumber)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDate)
    .ToListAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

```sql
  // Generated Sql:
SELECT "l"."Id", "l"."EventDate", "l"."GroupingAttribute", "l"."NotificationState"
   FROM "LTable" AS "l"
   WHERE ("l"."NotificationState" <> 1)
   ORDER BY "l"."EventDate" DESC
```